# How to force proftpd to use passive mode by default?

Tags: backup, ftp, proftpd

Any time I want to upload a file to proftpd I need to type in the command

```
passive
```

Problem is: when I do use some ready to go scripts like `backup-manager`, I cannot pass there `ftp -p` option, so I would like the proftpd to be set as passive by default (backup manager passive ftp option does not seem to work).

Is there a way to set up the proftpd to use passive by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision to use passive or active mode is only controlled from the FTP client side. There is no way for the FTP server to suggest to the client which of these modes should be used. This is not specific to proftpd but is how the FTP protocol works.